# session variables not logged in firefox; works well in chrome and IE

Tags: php, session, firefox

this issue has been driving me crazy.. i am trying to set session variables in login form once the credentials are validated... but the session variables are not logged in firefox but works perfectly in IE and in Chrome.. not sure what causes the issue.. see my code snippets below

```
 func.call();
 document.location.href = 'service.php';


call()

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
                      //window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                      return;
     }                else 
    {
   document.getElementById("error_part").innerHTML = '';//<img src="../animation/ajax-loader.gif">';
     }
  }
                    var myurl = 'session/session_start.php';
                    parms="?username="+username+"&email="+email;
                    var modurl = myurl+parms;
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", modurl, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
```

and the file - session_start.php:

```
$_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
 $_SESSION['role']=$row['role'];
 session_write_close();
```

Comment: the cookies are enabled in firefox; also php session start codes are written at top of every page... anyother suggestions please.. thanks!

Comment: When you view cookies in FF, do you see PHPSESSID?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more.. (am not aware of phpsessid).. thanks!

Comment: PHPSESSID is the name of the cookie that PHP uses to store the session ID. View your cookies for the page, and check if this one is there.

Comment: i see this in php.ini file..
    session.name = PHPSESSID

Comment: You need to look in Firefox's list of cookies that it has stored for the page, to make sure it's storing this cookie.

Comment: this is the content of php.ini<br>
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 0

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

session.cookie_path = /

session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly =

Comment: can you please confirm if we need to mention the path... is it mandatory... thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't care what's in php.ini. How many times do I have to say that you need to check FIREFOX?

Comment: yes @Barmar.. i see the name phpsessid metioned as Name in FF cookie..

Comment: any suggestions please.. thanks!